# Substring and split in sql server

Tags: sql-server, substring

I have these data in my sql server  as you can see here :

```
1/2
1/4
2/23
12/13
1/10
...
```

I need to change these to `001,001,002,012,001,..`

I use this .but it doesn't work

```
LEFT(SheetNumber,LEN(SheetNumber)-CHARINDEX('/',SheetNumber))
```

My query

```
SELECT  [Id]

      ,LEFT(SheetNumber,LEN(SheetNumber)-CHARINDEX('/',SheetNumber))


      ,[SubmitDateTime]
  FROM [SPMS2].[dbo].[Lines] where SheetNumber  like '%/%'
```

[image]

Comment: `LEFT(SheetNumber,CHARINDEX('/',SheetNumber) - 1)` something like this?

Comment: @Mark yes it works but how about append 0 to the value ?I mean 001,002,011

Comment: Did you need the values as comma separated chain (as requested in your question and here again), or just as a column in the result set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to use LEN. Just use

```
LEFT(SheetNumber,CHARINDEX('/',SheetNumber) - 1)
```

To make it into 3 digits with 0 in the front, you could use something like this

```
Right('000' + LEFT(SheetNumber,CHARINDEX('/',SheetNumber) - 1), 3)
```

Comment: This approach to pad a number is dangerous. Try this with a four-digit number and you will get your number cut. Better use `REPLACE with STR`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
RIGHT('000' + LEFT(SheetNumber, CHARINDEX('/', SheetNumber) - 1), 3)
```

Comment: This approach to pad a number is dangerous. Try this with a four-digit number and you will get your number cut. Better use `REPLACE with STR`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(SheetNumber VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('1/2')
,('1/4')
,('2/23')
,('12/13')
,('1/10');

SELECT STUFF(
   (
    SELECT ',' + REPLACE(STR(LEFT(SheetNumber,CHARINDEX('/',SheetNumber) - 1),3),' ','0')
    FROM @tbl
    FOR XML PATH('')
   ),1,1,'');
```

The result

```
001,001,002,012,001
```